# Apache Tomcat - Display a custom error message like "You have typed an invalid url" instead of displaying "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found"

Tags: java, tomcat

This below url with myWebAppName should be the only valid url that Tomcat should process.

**https://hostname:port/myWebAppName**

The above is working as expected.

Also , the invalid urls given in the below format i.e junk characters given after webappname, also displays the custom "404.html" as expected.

**https://hostname:port/myWebAppName/xxxx**

Solution Requested : If we provide wrong web application name , the Tomcat Error Page is getting displayed instead of custom error page.

i.e https://hostname:port/**wrong**myWebAppName (or) https://hostname:port/abcd

**Location of 404.html** :  Tomcat/webapps/myWebAppName/404.html

Please assist as early as possible. Would be highly obligued if this can be solved in web.xml itself , as I have already delivered war for test.

Thanks in Advance,
Ags

Comment: Please add your controller code to se how you handle the exceptions

Comment: I have not written any controller code to handle it.

Comment: I have not written any controller code to handle it.

Comment: Only i gave <error-page>
        <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page> at the end of web.xml
Can we solve this web.xml itself ??

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml

```
<error-page>
       <error-code>404</error-code>
         <location>/NotFound.jsp</location>
   </error-page>
```

Comment: Already a 404 page is included in the below path Tomcat/webapps/myWebAppName/404.html.

Comment: It is not getting picked, if the webappp name is given wrongly.
It's picked if the webappname is correct followed by junk chars like below https://hostname:port/myWebAppName/xxxx

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following entry in Tomcat's server.xml file , restricts the version information getting displayed if the invalid webapp name is provided in URL.

(open tag) Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"        showReport="false" showServerInfo="false" (add close tag)

**The above solution is needed for :** Attackers provide invalid url and obtain the version information, and the vulnerabilities for that version are provided in the Tomcat Documentation,which might help attackers to hack sensible data passed across the web.

Comment: we are having same issue . Can it be fixed?